# how to retrieve the max value from view?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this view and I would like to SELECT the `maximum SALE PRICE`

```
[Barcode No]    [LType]     [Description    ]   [UOM]  [Sale Price]
045300005492    CF00683     PETER PAN PBUTTER   PCS    23.5
045300005492    CF00683     PETER PAN PBUTTER   PCS    13.5
045300005492    CF00683     PETER PAN PBUTTER   PCS    13.5
```

I tried to use the following `SQL` Statement  but it's not work for me :

```
select [Barcode No],[ITEM NO],[Description],[SUM],max([Sales Price]) 
from [Table1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the non aggregate column's in `group by`

```
select [Barcode No],[ITEM NO],[Description],[SUM],max([Sales Price]) 
from [Table1]
Group by [Barcode No],[ITEM NO],[Description],[SUM]
```

Or use `Window Function`

```
SELECT [Barcode No],[ITEM NO],[Description],[SUM],[Sales Price]
FROM   (SELECT [Barcode No],[ITEM NO],[Description],[SUM],[Sales Price],
               Row_number()OVER(partition BY [Barcode No], [ITEM NO], [Description], [SUM]
                   ORDER BY [Sales Price] DESC) rn
        FROM   [Table1])a
WHERE  rn = 1
```